# How to avoid delimiter character in BCP export?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

In my project, I need to use SQL 2008 BCP tool to export the result of a stored procedure into a fixed column width file. I used different approaches, but still couldn't get expected result. Things I tried are explained below.

*(The database table from where the SP is fetching values is designed with all columns as varchar with width as needed by the specification of the requirement.)*

**First I tried** (as per [this site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196735(v=sql.80).aspx))

```
bcp "my_sample_sp" queryout "C:\table_output.txt" -S <servername> -d <dbname> -U <username> -P <password> -c -t \0 -a 10000 -L 100
```

This gave me the result with a single space between all columns as delimiter. 
Unexpected. Dont need any delimiter.

**Second, I tried**

```
bcp "my_sample_sp" queryout "C:\table_output.txt" -S <servername> -d <dbname> -U <username> -P <password> -c -t \0x90 -a 10000 -L 100
```

This gave me the result with a hidden character between all columns as delimiter. 
Unexpected. Most editors and the end application consuming this file read that invisible value as one character.

**Third, I tried** with format file in bcp tool. (followed [this site](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/))

Created native format file using below command

```
bcp "my_sample_Table" format nul -n -f C:\format_file.fmt -S <servername> -d <dbname> -U <username> -P <password>
```

Created the flat file using this format file as below.

```
bcp "my_sample_sp" queryout C:\table_output.txt -f C:\format_file.fmt -S <servername> -d <dbname> -U <username> -P <password>
```

File is created with all unreadable characters. I understand that native option is to only create files readable by SQL servers. I tried almost all options around this which are mentioned in the referred site.

Using SQLCMD tool, I was able to create the required output. As the count of records I need to export would easily cross 5 million records, I was told that SQLCMD tool is not suggested for that much count.

I tried all possible approaches before posting here. Any help which can guide me in the correct direction to create a fixed width flat file from a SP output is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not try fixed length delimiters. See answer at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8aacb52-50bf-4d33-8ee8-bf88b02153ad/bcp-format-file-for-fixed-length-flat-file

Comment: You can use [no space  0x90  or  0x8F as described in the blog post](https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/bcp-file-without-field-delimiter/)

Comment: Create a view that concatenates all columns together. That way you are exporting a single column, so no delimiters are required. This might not be ideal if you have a large number of columns.

Comment: Hi kin, I already tried with 0x90 and 0x8F and they are giving hidden character delimiter. But when you open the file in Notepad++, they count as 3 characters. so, its not working for my need.

Comment: Hi garthmillar, you are right, we have more than 135 columns which are returned and the stored procedure is doing some casting also on most columns. Concatinating was a difficult option for us.

Comment: Hi RLF, I am still trying with the format file and different combinations. Will update this post if something works out well.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I am closing this thread. I found the work around by managing to combine all columns to one string as mentioned by garthmillar.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work by combining all columns into one single string from SQL and return it to BCP tool.

Comment: You can accept your answer (once you have enough reputation) or if you dont want this question, then you can delete it as well.